# Bazaar pull selected file

Tags: bazaar

In SVN we can update selected file:

```
svn up index.php
```

Can we do something like that in Bazaar?

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't update just one file. But you can merge required changes for one file from another (or master) branch:

```
bzr merge /path/to/branch/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is impossible. Bazaar operates at the repository level. You cannot checkout or update only a directory/file of the repository. Its always the whole thing.

But I could be wrong.